# ¿Porque Extjs 7 esconde los items del combobox despues de ocultar la ventana?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Cuando inicio y muestro la ventana aparece bien el combobox y lo grabo pero cuando lo muestro otra vez la ventana no me muestra las opciones del combobox y encontre que estaba en display; none, cuando le pongo manualmente por el inspector lo puedo.

```html
var cmbUsuario = new Ext.form.ComboBox(
{ 
name:'usu_iide', 
tpl: tplUsu, width : 450, 
queryMode: 'remote', 
displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', '', '{per_vnombre_completo} - {dep_vdes}', '' ), 
store :empleados, displayField:'per_vnombre_completo', valueField:'usu_iide', typeAhead: true,
loadingText: 'Searching...', 
minChars: 1,
//hideTrigger:true,
// mode: 'local',
triggerAction: 'all',
forceSelection : true, //queryCaching: false, itemSelector: 'div.x-boundlist-item', allowBlank:false,
listeners : { afterrender : function(){ this.getStore().load();
}, specialkey: function(f,e){ }
} })

var tplUsu =new Ext.XTemplate( '<div class="x-boundlist-item" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5";>', '{per_vnombre_completo}
' , '{dep_vdes}, {car_vdes}',
'',
'');
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Quiero visualizar los items del combobox despues de esconder la ventana

Comment: ¿Cómo se está escondiendo la ventana? Si se utiliza `destroy` el combobox desaparece y hay que cargarlo de nuevo. ¿Cuál es el código para ocultar la ventana?

Comment: Lo estoy ocultando con menuEntrada.hide(); donde yo creo menuEntrada=Ext.create('TutorialApp.view.menuentrada.Menuentrada');

Comment: No me explico porque despues cuando lo muestro la ventana no me muestra la lista del combobox me aparece en el html como display:none

Answer (score 0):

Bueno me di cuenta con el inspector que cuando creaba una nueva ventana crea nuevas instancias del mismo objeto asi le dije que si con esto fue la solución:

```html
if(menuEntrada){
  menuEntrada.show();
 }
 else
  menuEntrada=Ext.create('TutorialApp.view.menuentrada.Menuentrada');
```

Comment: Este es un error frequente en ExtJS, por ello es preferible trabajar con `xtype`. ¿Qué tutorial estás siguiendo?

Comment: Para serte sincera ninguno, que tutoriales me aconsejas ?

Comment: De la serie de Packt Publishesrs (https://subscription.packtpub.com/search?query=extjs&_ga=2.41727777.2090914039.1680448677-676072739.1505783068) el de Loiane Groner es muy bueno y te ayuda a evitar el error que tuviste (https://www.packtpub.com/product/mastering-ext-js/9781784390457#_ga=2.898610.2090914039.1680448677-676072739.1505783068). Es para ExtJS 5, pero a grandes rasgos es vigente para ExtJS 7: la arquitectura es prácticamente la misma.  Este otro también te puede ayudar y está próxima a aparecer la edición para ExtJS 7: https://www.extjs6gettingstarted.com/

Comment: muchas gracias voy a leerlos

Comment: Con mucho gusto :-)

Comment: Una preguntita más please, estoy usando extjs todo va bien hasta que sale conexion reiniciada pruebo otras pestañas si hay internet, cuando lo reinicio la computadora sale bien. parece que no inicia la libreria extjs o sera que me pusieron en su lista de ips negras?

Comment: Te soy sincero, no sé si tienen listas negras, ¿estás usando una versión de prueba o con licencia? Igual creo que en ambos casos debería funcionar. ¿Cómo estás construyendo la App? Puedes también probar a hacer una app de demo sencilla con Sencha CMS, p.e., y ver si funciona.

Comment: Estoy usando version gpl de extjs, me da el mismo error para extjs 6 y extjs 3.5 con un proyecto que se hizo antes y que está funcionando en diferentes computadoras

Comment: ¿Ensayaste a crear una nueva app y probar que funciona? Esto nos ayudará a obtener más info sobre el problema.

Comment: Si de hecho estoy haciendo una nueva aplicación y lo cree con el cmd sencha y sale lo mismo, parece que es mi computadora  :''(

Comment: Creo que está más relacionado con la versión GPL, de pronto estás utilizando algún componente que no viene incluido en esa versión.